# In Python argparse, is it possible to have paired --no-something/--something arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program in which I would like to have arguments like this:

```
--[no-]foo   Do (or do not) foo. Default is do.
```

Is there a way to get argparse to do this for me in versions of Python earlier than 3.9 (and for versions after that as well)?

Comment: No.  The "no-" prefix is highly localized.  It's not consistent in English ("un-" is also quite common.)

Comment: I think you have to write it yourself. I wish it had it built-in.

Comment: @S.Lott: That's true. This program will not have a global audience though. :-) And if such a possibility were available, I'd expect the prefix to be able to be customized in some way.

Comment: Global isn't the issue.  Language is the issue.  For the one language I know well, there are innumerable irregularities.  That's why there's not "automatic" feature.

Comment: @jterrace: I wish the `_add_action` API were documented and that `Action` was more than a simple container of attributes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

v3.9 has added an `action` class that does this.  From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html#action) (near the end of the `action` section)

> The     `BooleanOptionalAction` is available in `argparse` and adds support for boolean actions such as `--foo` and `--no-foo`:
>
> ```
> >>> import argparse
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction)
> >>> parser.parse_args(['--no-foo'])
> Namespace(foo=False)
> ```

---

To explore @wim's comment about not being mutually_exclusive.

```
In [37]: >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction)
Out[37]: BooleanOptionalAction(option_strings=['--foo', '--no-foo'], dest='foo', nargs=0, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

The last line shows that the `add_argument` created a `BooleanOptionalAction` Action class.

With various inputs:

```
In [38]: parser.parse_args('--foo'.split())
Out[38]: Namespace(foo=True)

In [39]: parser.parse_args('--no-foo'.split())
Out[39]: Namespace(foo=False)

In [40]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[40]: Namespace(foo=None)

In [41]: parser.parse_args('--no-foo --foo'.split())
Out[41]: Namespace(foo=True)
```

So you can supply both flags, with the last taking effect, over writing anything produced by the previous.  It's as though we defined two `Actions`, with the same `dest`, but different `True/False` const.

The key is that it defined two flag strings:

```
option_strings=['--foo', '--no-foo']
```

Part of the code for this new class:

```
class BooleanOptionalAction(Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 ...):

        _option_strings = []
        for option_string in option_strings:
            _option_strings.append(option_string)

            if option_string.startswith('--'):
                option_string = '--no-' + option_string[2:]
                _option_strings.append(option_string)

     ...

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if option_string in self.option_strings:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, not option_string.startswith('--no-'))
```

So the action `__init__` defines the two flags, and the `__call__` checks for the `no` part.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make them mutually exclusive.

Comment: @wim, I didn't pay much attention to this addition to `argparse`. (and with the move to `github` I'm more out of the loop.)  It creates just one `Action` object, with two flags.  To be mutually_exclusive, it would have had to create two Actions, one for the True side, and the other for the False side.

Answer (score 25):

Well, none of the answers so far are quite satisfactory for a variety of reasons. So here is my own answer for versions of Python earlier than 3.9:

```
class ActionNoYes(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, opt_name, dest, default=True, required=False, help=None):
        super(ActionNoYes, self).__init__(['--' + opt_name, '--no-' + opt_name], dest, nargs=0, const=None, default=default, required=required, help=help)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if option_string.starts_with('--no-'):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, False)
        else:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, True)
```

And an example of use:

```
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> p._add_action(ActionNoYes('foo', 'foo', help="Do (or do not) foo. (default do)"))
ActionNoYes(option_strings=['--foo', '--no-foo'], dest='foo', nargs=0, const=None, default=True, type=None, choices=None, help='Do (or do not) foo. (default do)', metavar=None)
>>> p.parse_args(['--no-foo', '--foo', '--no-foo'])
Namespace(foo=False)
>>> p.print_help()
usage: -c [-h] [--foo]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --foo, --no-foo  Do (or do not) foo. (default do)
```

Unfortunately, the `_add_action` member function isn't documented, so this isn't 'official' in terms of being supported by the API. Also, `Action` is mainly a holder class. It has very little behavior on its own. It would be nice if it were possible to use it to customize the help message a bit more. For example saying `--[no-]foo` at the beginning. But that part is auto-generated by stuff outside the `Action` class.

Comment: You might be able to use the `metavar` option somehow to get `--[no-]foo`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `startswith` instead of `starts_with`?

Comment: This is awesome! But why did you call is `ActionNoYes`? I had a momentary brain segfault :D

Comment: @corwin.amber - You think it should've been ActionYesNo? :-) I can't remember why I chose that order. It was 8 years ago after all.

Comment: Yes LoL... I was trying to create an `ActionYesNo` in my code, staring at the error message not seeing why it could not find it... perhaps it's just me. Regardless, your answer and @btel's adaptation were extremely useful.

Comment: Python 3.9 has this class build in, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837302/758345

Answer (score 10):

Does the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` of `argparse` help?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
exclusive_grp = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
exclusive_grp.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='do foo')
exclusive_grp.add_argument('--no-foo', action='store_true', help='do not do foo')
args = parser.parse_args()

print 'Starting program', 'with' if args.foo else 'without', 'foo'
print 'Starting program', 'with' if args.no_foo else 'without', 'no_foo'
```

Here's how it looks when run:

```
./so.py --help
usage: so.py [-h] [--foo | --no-foo]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo       do foo
  --no-foo    do not do foo

./so.py
Starting program without foo
Starting program without no_foo

./so.py --no-foo --foo
usage: so.py [-h] [--foo | --no-foo]
so.py: error: argument --foo: not allowed with argument --no-foo
```

This is different from the following in the mutually exclusive group allows *neither* option in your program (and I'm assuming that you want **options** because of the `--` syntax).  This implies one or the other:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo=', choices=('y', 'n'), default='y',
                    help="Do foo? (default y)")
```

If these are required (non-optional), maybe using [`add_subparsers()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869345/how-to-make-python-argparse-mutually-exclusive-group-arguments-without-prefix/8621697#8621697) is what you're looking for.

**Update 1**

Logically different, but maybe cleaner:

```
...
exclusive_grp.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', dest='foo', help='do foo')
exclusive_grp.add_argument('--no-foo', action='store_false', dest='foo', help='do not do foo')
args = parser.parse_args()

print 'Starting program', 'with' if args.foo else 'without', 'foo'
```

And running it:

```
./so.py --foo
Starting program with foo
./so.py --no-foo
Starting program without foo
./so.py
Starting program without foo
```

Comment: Could you set ``action='store_false'`` for ``--no-foo`` and set ``dest='foo'`` for both so that it shows up in a single variable?

Comment: @jterrace Yes.  Interesting suggestion.  I've added an updated solution.

Comment: nice. you could wrap it in a function like in @s-lott's answer and would be really nice

Comment: This is good, except the help is a little unnecessarily verbose. But at least the argument group thing keeps the related arguments stuck together.

Comment: Also, it does not allow '--foo' and '--no-foo' to be specified at the same time and have the last specified take precedence.

Comment: @Omnifarious True.  Why do you want let the user enter both and have the interpreter (deterministically) choose which one to use?

Comment: This is intended for environments where the arguments may be passed through multiple layers, each one prepending its own defaults for the values. Anyway, I came up with a good solution after pulling apart the module myself.

Comment: Omnifarious is correct.   Making it exclusive, means that --no-foo is superfluous (without semantic value).  It is always false unless --foo is specified.   The only way that --no-foo becomes other meaningless is if it can negate a previous --foo.

Answer (score 10):

I modified the solution of @Omnifarious to make it more like the standard actions:

```
import argparse

class ActionNoYes(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, default=None, required=False, help=None):

        if default is None:
            raise ValueError('You must provide a default with Yes/No action')
        if len(option_strings)!=1:
            raise ValueError('Only single argument is allowed with YesNo action')
        opt = option_strings[0]
        if not opt.startswith('--'):
            raise ValueError('Yes/No arguments must be prefixed with --')

        opt = opt[2:]
        opts = ['--' + opt, '--no-' + opt]
        super(ActionNoYes, self).__init__(opts, dest, nargs=0, const=None, 
                                          default=default, required=required, help=help)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings=None):
        if option_strings.startswith('--no-'):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, False)
        else:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, True)
```

You can add the Yes/No argument as you would add any standard option. You just need to pass `ActionNoYes` class in the `action` argument:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action=ActionNoYes, default=False)
```

Now when you call it:

```
>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo'])
Namespace(foo=True)
>> args = parser.parse_args(['--no-foo'])
Namespace(foo=False)
>> args = parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(foo=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Write your own subclass.

```
class MyArgParse(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def magical_add_paired_arguments( self, *args, **kw ):
        self.add_argument( *args, **kw )
        self.add_argument( '--no'+args[0][2:], *args[1:], **kw )
```

Comment: Hmm...  that's an interesting idea. Is there an idea of an 'argument object' that can parse things itself and maybe generate it's own help message? That would really do the trick.

Comment: @Omnifarious: "generate it's own help message"?  What can that possibly mean?   What's wrong with  adding more code as shown above?  If you want even more magical things to occur, you might find it easier to simply read the source to `argparse` yourself and see how it works internally.

Comment: Well, that's one of the big advantages of argparse. It generates the help messages and stuff for you. `add_argument` could be thought of as a function that constructs some sort of argument object that represents all the features of an argument... how to parse it, which variable to stuff it in, default values, how to generate help, all that stuff, and puts it into a nice list inside the parser. But you're right, I should just delve into the internals myself and see if I can fiddle it the way I want. If it doesn't work the way I imagine, it should. It's lots more flexible.

Comment: "add_argument could be thought of as a function"?  It **is** a method which constructs an argument object. That's what it actually does.  I don't get the comment.  What are you saying?

Comment: So it does work the way I imagine. There is an 'argument object' that's constructed. Which means you can instantiate a different argument object that implements the methods differently. It could, for example, just add a dictionary with all the values given to the `add_argument` method to a list of those dictionaries.

Comment: I'll repeat this, since you're ignoring it.  "you might find it easier to simply read the source to argparse yourself and see how it works internally"

Comment: I fully understood exactly what you were asking me to do. So I did it and found my answer. I've added it as an answer to this question. I was hoping that someone knew without me having to pull the module apart myself, but it seems that nobody did.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here's a full implementation of [S.Lott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234802/246801):

```
import argparse

class MyArgParse(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def magical_add_paired_arguments( self, *args, **kw ):
        exclusive_grp = self.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        exclusive_grp.add_argument( *args, **kw )
        new_action = 'store_false' if kw['action'] == 'store_true' else 'store_true'
        del kw['action']
        new_help = 'not({})'.format(kw['help'])
        del kw['help']
        exclusive_grp.add_argument( '--no-'+args[0][2:], *args[1:], 
                           action=new_action,
                           help=new_help, **kw )

parser = MyArgParse()
parser.magical_add_paired_arguments('--foo', action='store_true',
                                    dest='foo', help='do foo')
args = parser.parse_args()

print 'Starting program', 'with' if args.foo else 'without', 'foo'
```

Here's the output:

```
./so.py --help
usage: so.py [-h] [--foo | --no-foo]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo       do foo
  --no-foo    not(do foo)
```

Comment: This is very nice, but has a couple of disadvantages. First it does allow specifying both `--foo` and `--no-foo` on the command line and having the last one take precedence. Secondly, the help is unnecessarily verbose, even though the mutually exclusive group thing does put them together. I went my own way and detailed my approach in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Extending https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236426/1695680 's answer

```
import argparse

class ActionFlagWithNo(argparse.Action):
    """
        Allows a 'no' prefix to disable store_true actions.
        For example, --debug will have an additional --no-debug to explicitly disable it.
    """
    def __init__(self, opt_name, dest=None, default=True, required=False, help=None):
        super(ActionFlagWithNo, self).__init__(
            [
                '--' + opt_name[0],
                '--no-' + opt_name[0],
            ] + opt_name[1:],
            dest=(opt_name[0].replace('-', '_') if dest is None else dest),
            nargs=0, const=None, default=default, required=required, help=help,
        )

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if option_string.startswith('--no-'):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, False)
        else:
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, True)

class ActionFlagWithNoFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    """
        This changes the --help output, what is originally this:

            --file, --no-file, -f

        Will be condensed like this:

            --[no-]file, -f
    """

    def _format_action_invocation(self, action):
        if action.option_strings[1].startswith('--no-'):
            return ', '.join(
                [action.option_strings[0][:2] + '[no-]' + action.option_strings[0][2:]]
                + action.option_strings[2:]
            )
        return super(ActionFlagWithNoFormatter, self)._format_action_invocation(action)


def main(argp=None):
    if argp is None:
        argp = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            formatter_class=ActionFlagWithNoFormatter,
        )
        argp._add_action(ActionFlagWithNo(['flaga', '-a'], default=False, help='...'))
        argp._add_action(ActionFlagWithNo(['flabb', '-b'], default=False, help='...'))

        argp = argp.parse_args()
```

This yields help output like so:

```
usage: myscript.py [-h] [--flaga] [--flabb]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --[no-]flaga, -a  ...
  --[no-]flabb, -b  ...
```

Gist version here, pull requests welcome :)
https://gist.github.com/thorsummoner/9850b5d6cd5e6bb5a3b9b7792b69b0a5

Answer (score 2):

Actualy I beleive there is a better answer to this...

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo',
                     action='store_true',
                     default=True,
                     help="Sets foo arg to True. If not included defaults to tru")

parser.add_argument('--no-foo',
                    action="store_const", 
                    const=False,
                    dest="foo",
                    help="negates --foo so if included then foo=False")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Does this work with Python pre-3.9 and with Python 2.7? Because for 3.9 and later, there is a better answer.

Comment: I like this solution!  Putting "--foo" and "--no-foo" into a mutually exclusive group might produce a better user experience.

foo_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
foo_group.add_argument(...

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing this question and the answers I wrote my own function to deal with this:

```
def on_off(item):
    return 'on' if item else 'off'

def argparse_add_toggle(parser, name, **kwargs):
    """Given a basename of an argument, add --name and --no-name to parser

    All standard ArgumentParser.add_argument parameters are supported
    and fed through to add_argument as is with the following exceptions:
    name     is used to generate both an on and an off
             switch: --<name>/--no-<name>
    help     by default is a simple 'Switch on/off <name>' text for the
             two options. If you provide it make sure it fits english
             language wise into the template
               'Switch on <help>. Default: <default>'
             If you need more control, use help_on and help_off
    help_on  Literally used to provide the help text for  --<name>
    help_off Literally used to provide the help text for  --no-<name>
    """
    default = bool(kwargs.pop('default', 0))
    dest = kwargs.pop('dest', name)
    help = kwargs.pop('help', name)
    help_on  = kwargs.pop('help_on',  'Switch on {}. Default: {}'.format(help, on_off(defaults)))
    help_off = kwargs.pop('help_off', 'Switch off {}.'.format(help))

    parser.add_argument('--' + name,    action='store_true',  dest=dest, default=default, help=help_on)
    parser.add_argument('--no-' + name, action='store_false', dest=dest, help=help_off)
```

It can be used like this:

```
defaults = {
    'dry_run' : 0,
    }

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Fancy Script",
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
argparse_add_toggle(parser, 'dry_run', default=defaults['dry_run'],
                    help_on='No modifications on the filesystem. No jobs started.',
                    help_off='Normal operation')
parser.set_defaults(**defaults)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Help output looks like this:

```
  --dry_run             No modifications on the filesystem. No jobs started.
  --no-dry_run          Normal operation
```

I prefer the approach of subclassing `argparse.Action` that the other answers are suggesting over my plain function because it makes the code using it cleaner, and easier to read.

This code has the advantage of having a standard default help, but also a `help_on` and `help_off` to reconfigure the rather stupid defaults.

Maybe someone can integrate.