# optional python arguments without dashes but with additional parameters?

Tags: python, argparse

what I'd like to do in Python is accept arguments of the following format:

```
script.py START | STOP | STATUS | MOVEABS <x> <y> | MOVEREL <x> <y>
```

So in other words,

1. I don't want to deal with hyphens;
2. I have multiple possibilities, ONE of which is required;
3. Each is mutually exclusive;
4. Some of the commands (E.G. moveabs and moverel) have additional required arguments, but these args  and  should not be present with any other argument.

Can this be done in python and would I use argparse or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It is all documented here: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make python argparse mutually exclusive group arguments without prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869345/how-to-make-python-argparse-mutually-exclusive-group-arguments-without-prefix)

Comment: @Constantinius The question was not about `argparse`.

Comment: My answer elaborates on the subparser use in the accepted answer in Canstantinius's 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`add_parser` with subparsers would do the trick

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='script.py')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
for cmd in ['START', 'STOP', 'STATUS']:
    sp.add_parser(cmd)
for cmd in ['MOVEABS', 'MOVEREL']:
    spp = sp.add_parser(cmd)
    spp.add_argument('x', type=float)
    spp.add_argument('y', type=float)
parser.print_help()
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

producing the likes of:

```
2137:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack23304740.py MOVEREL -h
usage: script.py [-h] {START,STOP,STATUS,MOVEABS,MOVEREL} ...

positional arguments:
  {START,STOP,STATUS,MOVEABS,MOVEREL}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

usage: script.py MOVEREL [-h] x y

positional arguments:
  x
  y

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and

```
2146:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack23304740.py MOVEREL 1.0 2.0
...
Namespace(cmd='MOVEREL', x=1.0, y=2.0)
```

and

```
2147:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack23304740.py START
...
Namespace(cmd='START')
```

The MOVEREL arguments could be named `<x>` and `<y>`, but then you'd have to access them via `args['<y>']` instead of `args.y`. `metavar='<x>'` could be used to change the display but not the Namespace name.

You could also use `spp.add_argument('point', nargs=2, type=float)`.  Unfortunately there's a bug that keeps us from using a metavar in this `nargs=2` case, http://bugs.python.org/issue14074.

Answer (score 5):

Using `docopt` you can do this quite easily.

## Install `docopt` first:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

## Write the `script.py`:

```
"""
Usage:
    script.py (start | stop | status | moveabs <x> <y> | moverel <x> <y>)
"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

## and run it:

first showing basic help:

```
$ python script.py
Usage:
    script.py (start | stop | status | moveabs <x> <y> | moverel <x> <y>)
```

then try subcommands:

start

```
$ python script.py start
{'<x>': None,
 '<y>': None,
 'moveabs': False,
 'moverel': False,
 'start': True,
 'status': False,
 'stop': False}
```

stop

```
$ python script.py stop
{'<x>': None,
 '<y>': None,
 'moveabs': False,
 'moverel': False,
 'start': False,
 'status': False,
 'stop': True}
```

moveabs

```
$ python script.py moveabs 11 22
{'<x>': '11',
 '<y>': '22',
 'moveabs': True,
 'moverel': False,
 'start': False,
 'status': False,
 'stop': False}
```

moverel

```
$ python script.py moverel 11 22
{'<x>': '11',
 '<y>': '22',
 'moveabs': False,
 'moverel': True,
 'start': False,
 'status': False,
 'stop': False}
```

Comment: The `argparse` solution does not produce unnecessary data fields, so I find it cleaner and more robust.