# python 2.7 argparse: How can a mutually exclusive group be created in a normal argument group?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I created the next "parent" parser:

```
parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
base_group = parser.add_argument_group(title = "global arguments")                                                     
base_group.add_argument("-l", "--log-file", metavar="FILE", help="set log file (default no log)")                      
base_group.add_argument("-c", "--clear-log", action="store_true", default=False, help="clear log file before logging") 

mutex_group = base_group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()                                                                
mutex_group.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true", default=False, help="print logs verbosity")           
mutex_group.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", action="store_true", default=False, help="suppress every normal output")
```

If I use this parser as parent in an other one, then I would like to see in the help the next:

> ```
> usage: my_program.py [-h] [-l FILE] [-c] [-v | -q ] [<the parent arguments ...>]
>
> Desc...
>
> optional arguments:
>    <the my_program.py arguments>
>
> global arguments:
>   -l FILE, --log-file FILE
>                     set log file (default no log)
>   -c, --clear-log       clear log file before logging
>   -v, --verbose         print logs verbosity
>   -q, --quiet           suppress every normal output
> ```

But unfortunately the arguments from mutex group (-v and -q) are shown in "optional arguments" part. Why? Is it a bug? Or do I make something wrongly?

**UPDATE:**

I created a bug for this problem: http://bugs.python.org/issue25882.
See this bug for my simple code and its output for this situation.

Comment: Mutually exclusive argument groups aren't named, they are always shown in their parent group (here "global arguments") (see, e.g., the output in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869345/how-to-make-python-argparse-mutually-exclusive-group-arguments-without-prefix)

Comment: @hlt but in this case the parent group is the "base_group", isn't?

Comment: I think you misunderstand me :). The output in my question would be the good solution for me, but not this is happened. The -v and -q are shown in "optional arguments" part in what the arguments of child parser are shown. I would like if -v and -q could be seen in "global arguments" what is the arguments of parent parser.

Comment: It works for me on 2.7.9... odd.

Comment: my python version is 2.7.3, maybe then this is a bug ... I will try to check it in checklogs of python, thx the checking @hlt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent_parser` behaves as you want, but when used as a `parents` it does not.

If I add to your code (correcting a use of `parser`):

```
parent_parser.print_help()

print('-------------')
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent_parser])
parser.print_help()
```

I get (in all versions)

```
1317:~/mypy$ python3.5 stack34308904.py 
usage: stack34308904.py [-l FILE] [-c] [-v | -q]

global arguments:
  -l FILE, --log-file FILE
                        set log file (default no log)
  -c, --clear-log       clear log file before logging
  -v, --verbose         print logs verbosity
  -q, --quiet           suppress every normal output
-------------
usage: stack34308904.py [-h] [-l FILE] [-c] [-v | -q]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         print logs verbosity
  -q, --quiet           suppress every normal output

global arguments:
  -l FILE, --log-file FILE
                        set log file (default no log)
  -c, --clear-log       clear log file before logging
```

It's evident from comments in the '_add_container_actions' method (the method that copies groups and arguments from a parent to a child), that the developers anticipated the situation where a mutually_exclusive_group was embedded in an argument_group, but haven't yet tried to get that working correctly.

The simplest immediate fix is to skip the `parents` bit, and just define the groups and arguments in the main parser.  `parents` are a convenience in some cases (and a nuisance in others), but rarely necessary.

---

There is now a bug/issue;

A tentative fix is to add 2 lines to
`argparse._ActionsContainer._add_container_actions`

```
....
# add container's mutually exclusive groups
# NOTE: if add_mutually_exclusive_group ever gains title= and
# description= then this code will need to be expanded as above
for group in container._mutually_exclusive_groups:
    #print('container title',group._container.title)
    mutex_group = self.add_mutually_exclusive_group(
        required=group.required)
    # new lines - updates the `_container attribute of the new mx group
    mx_container = title_group_map[group._container.title]
    mutex_group._container = mx_container
```

---

http://bugs.python.org/issue25882 - issue with a monkey patch file.